# Create Language plperl - Error: could not load library plperl.dll

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, perl

When I `create language plperl` , I get error: *ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/plperl.dll": The specified module could not be found*.

But in my computer,  "plperl.dll" file is exist in "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/..." folder   ( I can not post illustrative image, this forum require >= 10 reputations)

And if I `select * pg_pltemplate`, I get:

```
-[ RECORD 4 ]-+-------------------------
tmplname      | plperl
tmpltrusted   | t
tmpldbacreate | t
tmplhandler   | plperl_call_handler
tmplinline    | plperl_inline_handler
tmplvalidator | plperl_validator
tmpllibrary   | $libdir/plperl
```

Comment: If the file exists, the next question is: does the OS user running postgres have permission to load it? You might make this easier by disclosing your OS. Windows something I suppose?

Comment: Thanks Erwin Brandsetter. I've grant permission for user "postgres" (right click in folder -> properties->Edit->Add) and it can not fix . Library folder   ("C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\lib") have "plpgsql.dll", plperl.dll . But I can create or replace language "plpgsql" (of course, it load "plpgsql.dll" from this library). So , I think "permission" is not a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because I missed 3 files dll (MSVCR90.DLL, PERL514.DLL, IESHIMS.DLL) in Windows I could not install the language pl/Perl.

Here my steps to solve:

- Using  "Dependency Walker" tool to check dll files missing (if any). After installing, you open plperl.dll file and find errors.
- Install dll files missing.
- Install ActivePerl (to install Perl on window, It will automatically set Perl bin folder to windows environment variable)
- Restart postgresql service
- Test:

  ```
      createlang -U postgres plperl postgre  (it's ok)
      CREATE or replace LANGUAGE plperl      (it's ok)
  ```

Download (I just can post 2 links)

- Dependency Walker tool: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Reference: http://www.mkyong.com/database/install-perl-in-postgresql-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found/

Comment: I think you can use Strawberry Perl too, right?

Comment: Ah, I remember that I didn't use it.